# I need to find prime numbers in this list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find the prime numbers from a list with the following specification:
A) If the numbers are prime, the code should print "[number] is a prime number."
B) If the number is NOT a prime number, it should print "[number] is not a prime number", and a factor of that number, other than 1 and the number itself: "[factor] is a factor of [number]".

```
check_prime = [26, 39, 51, 53, 57, 79, 85].
for num in check_prime:
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print("{} is NOT a prime number, because {} is a factor of {}".format(num, i, num))
            break

    if i == num -1:    
        print("{} IS a prime number".format(num))
```

Can someone explain this code? I am unable to understand why there num-1 to find prime number. Why we have not used else statement there?

Comment: You're right - the for-loop can have an `else` block to catch the case where `break` is never executed. I suppose the person who wrote this code did not know that, so they are trying to test whether `i` got to the last step of the range. But that is buggy, since if `num` is `2` (which is prime), `i` will never be incremented.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that `range(2, num)` generates numbers starting from 2 up to `num-1` because `range(0,n)` generates numbers in general from 0 to n-1. So your `i` will run from 2 to `num-1`. That is why you check `if i == num -1:` to see if all the values of `i` have been used to check for the prime number.

Answer (score 1):

This is sloppy code.

The logic is that the number is prime if and only if you went through all possible factors less than the number.  In this case, `i == num-1`.

There are better ways to determine whether a number is prime.  You can search for "determine prime Python" and get many hits with better code and more straightforward logic.

For instance, this is more clear:

```
import math

check_prime = [26, 39, 51, 53, 57, 79, 85].
for num in check_prime:
    is_prime = True
    for i in range(2, int(num**0.5) + 1):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            is_prime = False
            break

    if is_prime:    
        print("{} IS a prime number".format(num))
    else:
        print("{} is NOT a prime number, because {} is a factor of {}".format(num, i, num))
```

Is that easier for you to follow?

Comment: `math.sqrt` returns a float, but `range` needs integer arguments. You can also perform a square root without any imports with `num**0.5`. Also, `is_prime` basically sets a flag to see if the loop stops with a `break`, which is what `for..else` basically does.

Answer (score 1):

Since the inner loop iterates `i` over `range(2, num)`, `i` would become `num - 1` in the end if the loop does not encounter a `break` due to finding a divisor, which is how a prime number is determined.

Alternatively, you can use the `for-else` construct to achieve the goal of determining that the number is a prime only if the loop does not encounter a `break` in a cleaner way:

```
for num in check_prime:
    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print("{} is NOT a prime number, because {} is a factor of {}".format(num, i, num))
            break
    else:
        print("{} IS a prime number".format(num))
```